# Spliting a Dataframe with unique and duplicates

Tags: java, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Input Dataframe :

```
df=
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  E|
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  F|
|  a|  b|  d|  d|  H|
|  a|  c|  c|  d|  E|
|  a|  a|  c|  d|  E|
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  L|
|  a|  c|  c|  d|  E|
+---+---+---+---+---+`
```

code

```
String[] col={"1", "2","3"};
Dataframe a=df.dropDuplicates(col);
Dataframe b=df.except(a);
```

```
a.show();
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  a|  c|  d|  E|
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  E|
|  a|  b|  d|  d|  H|
|  a|  c|  c|  d|  E|
+---+---+---+---+---+`

b.show();
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  L|
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  F|
+---+---+---+---+---+`
```

But I need a output for b is

```
b.show();
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  L|
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  F|
|  a|  c|  c|  d|  E|
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: your required output is incorrect

Comment: try `exceptAll`